# Passing a ViewModel object as a Json object to view

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Im trying to pass a ViewModel object as a Json object to view.

`InquiryOrderViewModel`

```
public class InquiryOrderViewModel
{
    public InquiryOrder InquiryOrder { get; set; }        
}
```

`InquiryOrder` model

```
public class InquiryOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int InquiryOrderId { get; set; }

    public string InquiryOrderName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductType")]
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

`InquiryOrderIndex` view and the script to retrieve Json object

```
@model eKnittingData.InquiryOrderViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "InquiryOrder", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "IoResult", OnSuccess = "ajaxSuccess" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.InquiryOrder.InquiryOrderName)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.InquiryOrder.ProductTypeId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ProductTList, "Select")

    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="saveProp" class="btn btn-success" />
}

<script>
        $(document).on('click', '.myUpdateLink', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var inqOrdId = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("getForUpdate", "InquiryOrder")',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: { InquiryOrderId: inqOrdId },
                success: function (io) {
                    alert("Successfully came from controller");
                    //How should i access elements in 'io'
                }
            }); 
        });
        </script>
```

`JsonResult` in controller

```
public JsonResult getForUpdate(int InquiryOrderId)
    {
        var objContext = new KnittingdbContext();

        var inquiryOrderViewModel = new InquiryOrderViewModel();
        var inquiryOrderObj = (InquiryOrder)objContext.InquiryOrders.Where(a => a.InquiryOrderId == InquiryOrderId).FirstOrDefault();
        inquiryOrderViewModel.InquiryOrder = inquiryOrderObj;

        return Json(new { io = inquiryOrderViewModel }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

`alert("Successfully came from controller")` fires successfully. But im not able access properties of `InquiryOrderViewModel`(ex:`InquiryOrder` and then properties of `InquiryOrder`) of it. What i want is, to access the values of that properties and bind those with `InquiryOrderIndex` view(`InquiryOrderName`,`ProductTypeId`). All help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To access a say `InquiryOrderName` then its `var name = io.io.InquiryOrder.InquiryOrderName;` (but its unclear why you not just using `return Json(inquiryOrderObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`? and what is the point of your so called 'view model' which is not a view model)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Thank you :) Once i changed it like `return Json(inquiryOrderObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` as you said, it started working. Actually in `InquiryOrderViewModel` there are many other class references also included even though i didn't show it, to pass to the `InquiryOrderIndex` view. That's why i mentioned it a view model. Pls correct me if im wrong. And could you pls tell me how should  i bind these returned values to razor controllers in view?(to `InquiryOrderName` textbox and to `ProductTypeId` dropdownlist)

Comment: Firstly a view model is not a class for holding multiple data models, and the fact that you still use `ViewBag` suggests your not not understanding what a view model is. What exactly do you want to do? Update the text in the textbox and select an option in the dropdownlist? Or generate a new set of options as well? And what are the `ProductTypeId` and `ProductType` properties used for?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Thanks for correcting me. I'll read more about that. Actually the above view is used for save. But now im going to use it as a update view. I changed `Save` submit button to a `button` using jquery and add another `submit button` called `Update` (which is not shown here) so that i can use this view as the update view also. So i want to update the texts in the textboxes and to update the selected value of dropdownlists with returned values. How should i do that? `ProductTypeId ` is the property that binds ddl value and `ProductType` is related to foreignkey.

Comment: Then you should not be returning a model, you should just be returning `return Json(new { Name = inquiryOrderObj.InquiryOrderName, Product = inquiryOrderObj.ProductTypeId }, ....);` - you only pass the data you need.  Then to set the textbox, use `success: function (data) { $('#InquiryOrder_InquiryOrderName').val(data.Name);`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Thank you :)  But what if i want to return a list to view? Let's assume this list `List<InquiryComponentDetailVM> InquiryComponentDetails` in `InquiryOrderViewModel` and i have a 'foreach' in the view. How should i return that list?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95435/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-isuru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passing back an anonymous object named with a property named `io` which contains your view model, so to access it in the ajax success callback, it would be

```
success: function (io) {
    var name = io.io.InquiryOrder.InquiryOrderName;
```

But you should not be passing the view model back to the client unless that view model contains only those properties you need in the view (and from your comments to contains other properties including data models). The `Json()` method serializes your models so your sending back much more data across the wire than you need therefore degrading performance. Instead, send back just what you need

```
var order = (InquiryOrder)objContext.InquiryOrders.Where(a => a.InquiryOrderId == InquiryOrderId).FirstOrDefault();
var data = new { name = order.InquiryOrderName, product = order.ProductTypeId };
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and then in the view, to set the values of the textbox and dropdownlist

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#InquiryOrder_InquiryOrderName').val(data.name);
    $('#InquiryOrder_ProductTypeId').val(data.product);
}
```

Comment: Valuable information and you got me to the correct path. Thank you so much. Instead of `$('#InquiryOrder_InquiryOrderName').val(data.name);` if i use `$('#InquiryOrderName').val(data.name);` the data doesn't get binded. Are those two are same or different?

Comment: No they are different. `@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.InquiryOrder.InquiryOrderName)` generates an input with `id="InquiryOrder_InquiryOrderName"` (not `id="InquiryOrderName"`)

Comment: But if we consider `ProductType` dropdownlist here, if i want to capture the change, i just use `$('#ProductTypeId').change(..)` not `$('#InquiryOrder_ProductTypeId').change(..)`. Could you pls tell me the difference?

Comment: What your claiming will not work unless you have overridden the id attribute (using `new { id = "ProductTypeId" }` in the`DropDownListFor()` method).

Comment: your above comment clarifies lot of things to me that i was not aware of. Thank you so much for information.. :)